# Getting the parameter names by giving the procedure name - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to get the parameter names of a stored procedure in a database by giving the procedure name and database name in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, I gave a solution using `mysql.proc`. @Michael-sqlbot pointed out that it would be much better to use `information_schema.parameters`. This revised solution follows that suggestion.

Execute these queries to describe and illustrate the data in `information_schema.parameters`:

```
EXPLAIN information_schema.parameters;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.parameters;
```

This is the revised solution:

```
SELECT parameter_name 
  FROM information_schema.parameters
 WHERE specific_schema = 'my_db'
   AND specific_name = 'my_procedure'
 ORDER BY ordinal_position
;

parameter_name
-----------------
p_first_param
p_second_param
p_third_param
```

If you need them in a single row, `GROUP_CONCAT` could be used to give you comma-separated names:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(parameter_name) params 
  FROM information_schema.parameters
 WHERE specific_schema = 'my_db'
   AND specific_name = 'my_procedure'
 ORDER BY ordinal_position
;

params
------------------------------------------
p_first_param,p_second_param,p_third_param
```

Comment: I get an error that SELECT command denied to user <userid> for table 'proc' @Zach Victor

Comment: The `mysql` schema may not be accessible to your user. You must grant the application user the `SELECT` privilege on the `mysql` schema.

Comment: @ZachVictor the [`information_schema.parameters`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/parameters-table.html) table seems to be a cleaner solution and should include all stored routines for which the user has permissions.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, that is a much better idea. I don't know why I had `information_schema` amnesia. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This revised solution gave me a perfect result (without granting any permissions)